# MySQL Select Where spliting results into different column

Tags: mysql, split

I'm trying to split results into different column, I've been searching for that for few days but couldn't find the correct term of what I'd like to do. I'm probably using wrong key words.

I have a table like this:

```
Timestamp    System    Value
1             1          13
1             2          12
1             3          5
2             1          37
2             2          12
2             3          55
3             1          12
3             2          45
3             3          45
```

And I would like to get a result like that:

```
Timestamp, System1val, System2val, System3val
1             13            12        5
2             37            12        55
3             12            45        45
```

I'm pretty sure it's possible to do it. I've been close by using:

```
SELECT  
    FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) as time,  
    CASE System
        WHEN '1' THEN System
        END AS System1val,
    CASE System
        WHEN '2' THEN pyr.measure_conv
        END AS System2val,
    CASE System
        WHEN '3' THEN pyr.measure_conv
        END AS System3val
FROM
```

This actually return different fields and fill in with NULL value. The final goal would be to group by timestamp and have all three values

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is `pivot`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a 'cross-tab' challenge.  You need to structure stuff in this way...

```
SELECT
Timestamp,
SUM(CASE WHEN System=X THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS X,
SUM(CASE WHEN System=Y THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS Y
FROM System
GROUP BY Timestamp
```

Comment: @Damien It should be pretty efficient. When you don't have functions which do the behaviour for you like sql server's PIVOT then this is the 'design pattern' that gets followed as it's the easiest to understand and is compact - that being said it's not good for an unknown number of values you want transposed but that is a challenge I'd handle in the presentation layer.

Comment: I'm still having a problem, with this structure, each entry is returned three times and therefor the sum is returning a value three times higher. I could divide by three but it should be a cleaner way to go. the SUM block the use of groupby x an y which could have solved this issue.

Comment: D'oh, forgot my group by for the column you are 'pivoting' the info on

Comment: Yes even with the group the values are returned three times, I'm quite surprised actually. If I group by timestamp, system1, system2, etc then it's fine, but this is not compatible with the SUM

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT  
    timestamp time,  
    SUM(CASE WHEN system = 1 THEN value ELSE NULL END) System1val,
    SUM(CASE WHEN system = 2 THEN value ELSE NULL END) System2val,
    SUM(CASE WHEN system = 3 THEN value ELSE NULL END) System3val
FROM Table1
 GROUP BY timestamp
```

Output:

```
| TIME | SYSTEM1VAL | SYSTEM2VAL | SYSTEM3VAL |
-----------------------------------------------
|    1 |         13 |         12 |          5 |
|    2 |         37 |         12 |         55 |
|    3 |         12 |         45 |         45 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79e73/4)** demo